# how to get expected elements values from json object

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, ajax, json

how to use json_decode() method for this complex json object?particular i want to get value of x and value of y.

```
    {"list":{"num":"11","type":"map"},"tagName":"resultset","childList":[{"list":{"addr":"Delhi","type":"exact","z":"3","y":"28.6327","x":"77.2197"},"tagName":"result","childList":[]},{"list":{"addr":"Delhi","type":"alternate"},"tagName":"result","childList":[]},{"list":{"addr":"Deoli,New > Delhi,Delhi","type":"alternate"},"tagName":"result","childList":[]},{"list":{"addr":"Pur > Delhi,New > Delhi,Delhi","type":"alternate"},"tagName":"result","childList":[]},{"list":{"addr":"Sabhaypur > Delhi,New > Delhi,Delhi","type":"alternate"},"tagName":"result","childList":[]},{"list":{"addr":"Chirag > Delhi,New > Delhi,Delhi","type":"alternate"},"tagName":"result","childList":[]},{"list":{"addr":"Delhi > Tyre Delhi,Kilokri,New > Delhi,Delhi","type":"alternate"},"tagName":"result","childList":[]},{"list":{"addr":"New > Delhi,Delhi","type":"alternate"},"tagName":"result","childList":[]},{"list":{"addr":"New > Delhi > District,Delhi","type":"alternate"},"tagName":"result","childList":[]},{"list":{"addr":"Babarpur,New > Delhi,Delhi","type":"alternate"},"tagName":"result","childList":[]},{"list":{"addr":"Barwala,New > Delhi,Delhi","type":"alternate"},"tagName":"result","childList":[]}]} 

here is array object

    Array > Array ( [list] => Array ( [num] => 11 [type] => map ) [tagName] => > resultset [childList] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [list] => Array ( > [addr] => Delhi [type] => exact [z] => 3 [y] => 28.6327 [x] => 77.2197 > ) [tagName] => result [childList] => Array ( ) ) [1] => Array ( [list] > => Array ( [addr] => Delhi [type] => alternate ) [tagName] => result [childList] => Array ( ) ) [2] => Array ( [list] => Array ( [addr] => > Deoli,New Delhi,Delhi [type] => alternate ) [tagName] => result > [childList] => Array ( ) ) [3] => Array ( [list] => Array ( [addr] => > Pur Delhi,New Delhi,Delhi [type] => alternate ) [tagName] => result > [childList] => Array ( ) ) [4] => Array ( [list] => Array ( [addr] => > Sabhaypur Delhi,New Delhi,Delhi [type] => alternate ) [tagName] => > result [childList] => Array ( ) ) [5] => Array ( [list] => Array ( > [addr] => Chirag Delhi,New Delhi,Delhi [type] => alternate ) [tagName] > => result [childList] => Array ( ) ) [6] => Array ( [list] => Array ( [addr] => Delhi Tyre Delhi,Kilokri,New Delhi,Delhi [type] => alternate > ) [tagName] => result [childList] => Array ( ) ) [7] => Array ( [list] > => Array ( [addr] => New Delhi,Delhi [type] => alternate ) [tagName] => result [childList] => Array ( ) ) [8] => Array ( [list] => Array ( [addr] => New Delhi District,Delhi [type] => alternate ) [tagName] => > result [childList] => Array ( ) ) [9] => Array ( [list] => Array ( > [addr] => Babarpur,New Delhi,Delhi [type] => alternate ) [tagName] => > result [childList] => Array ( ) ) [10] => Array ( [list] => Array ( > [addr] => Barwala,New Delhi,Delhi [type] => alternate ) [tagName] => > result [childList] => Array ( ) ) ) )
```

Comment: Please break your question into sentences and explain clearly what you are asking. Right now it is not clear.

Comment: `json_decode()` and `foreach()` or `array_walk_recursive` or a combination of both ?

Comment: i want to use values of X  and Y for my application . the app is in JS so i want to call my php file using ajax and want to get the data in success callback..

Answer (score 1):

If you are using jQuerys ajax, then you can access the response in the success method like so: (assuming you're doing a GET)

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "myphp.php",
    success: function() {
        var x = resp.childList[0].list.x;
        var y = resp.childList[0].list.y;
        $('#result').html('X: ' + x + 'Y: ' + y);
    }
});
```

Please see this on how to use jQuerys ajax with PHP. http://iviewsource.com/codingtutorials/learning-how-to-use-jquery-ajax-with-php-video-tutorial/

Comment: i want the result in a div like this- $('#result').html(data);

Comment: Have you already retrieved the data from the server via JS? If not,  read up on how to do so: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/.

Comment: is it  right ?                                                        $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "myphp.php",
  data: { x: "123", y: "321" }
})
  success: function(data){  
    var x = resp.childList[0].list.x;
    var y = resp.childList[0].list.y;   
  }
  })

Comment: my php file<?php
$location     = urlencode('delhi');
$str= "location=".$location;
 $ch=curl_init();
 curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,'http://myurl);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
 curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
 curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $str);

$result =  curl_exec($ch); 

print_r($result);

curl_close($ch);
 ?>
  })

Comment: @skriblez....your code is not working .i made changes and now its working :-).success: function(data){
        var x = data.childList[0].list.x;
        var y = data.childList[0].list.y;
        $("#"+ResultsId).append('X: ' + x + 'Y: ' + y);
        //$("#"+ResultsId).html(data);
    }

Comment: :i edited your answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

i got x and y like this  i am able to save my json response in html div like this.:-)

```
    function StartAjax(ResultsId){
        $.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          url: "myphp.php",
          cache: false,
         success: function (data) {
          data=eval("("+data+")");

            for (var x = 0; x < data.childList.length; x++) {
             if(data.childList[x].list.type=='exact')
             {
               y=data.childList[x].list.x;
               k=data.childList[x].list.y;
    }
)};
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <a href="#" onclick="StartAjax('ResultsId');">Click Here to see content from myphp.php</a>
    <div id="ResultsId"></div>
```

Comment: and added 1 line in myphp.php file $_POST[$result];